# jquery, qtip...why isn't my tooltip working?

Tags: jquery, qtip

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>
   <script>

     $('a_tip').qtip({
     content: 'This is an active list element',
     show: 'mouseover',
     hide: 'mouseout'
      })

   </script>
  </head>
<body>

 <div id = "a_tip">
  Want a tip?
 </div>

</body>
```

I have my jquery and qtip libraries in the right places - no errors in chrome console at all. I did my best following the tutorial on the qtip website, but can't see where I'm wrong. All I want is for the tooltip to show when the cursor is placed over 'Want a tip?' Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the code when DOM is ready and your missing the `#` for an id selector, try something like this:

```
<script>
 $(function(){//When DOM is ready
    $('#a_tip').qtip({
      content: 'This is an active list element',
      show: 'mouseover',
      hide: 'mouseout'
    });
 });

</script>
```

Also add the following style to make the qTip appear:

```
<style>
  #a_tip{
     display:inline
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for that - the missing id selector and $(function() I'm sure are part of the problem....but it's still not working. No errors in console at all. Maybe I have to put something more in the <div id = "a_tip"> part. I'll keep looking....

Comment: Everything seems fine, maybe you could move to qTip2, version 1 of qTip and 1.3 of jQuery are old an no longer maintained

Comment: I've created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rf90210/LfBzy/ The tip is working, but it is displayed at right of the div, I had to put a style  of `display:inline` for the qtip to show. You can configure positioning of qTip to avoid adding this styles

Comment: Ah! It's the css that does it, thanks. Now it works. I had no css at all. I have to say, the 'tutorials' at qtip could be a lot better. Put the 'display:inline' comment in your answer and I'll be happy to accept. The tooltip is missing borders with your div definition in the fiddle; works perfectly when defined like: #a_tip{
    display:inline;} Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have used the wrong selector. You need to use the `#id` selector.

```
$('#a_tip').qtip({ ... });
```

Secondly, to ensure that `#a_tip` exists when you do it, you need to do it on DOMReady event.

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#a_tip').qtip({ ... });
});
```

Comment: Cheers for that; two exact same comments at the same time! As above though, still not working. I'll look into it a bit more, or if you have any ideas yourself...